# For some reason, the first time my do-while loop executes, the scanner asks for input twice

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

It's been like this since I created a method for accepting user input. Before, the scanner was in the loop, but it was causing a different minor issue. I've never had this problem before..

```
    public static int input(){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    int guess;
    guess = scan.nextInt();
    return(guess);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    do{ 
        if (firstPromptIsPrinted){
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 20.");
        }
        guess = input();

        if (secondPromptIsPrinted){
            System.out.println("Nope ;). ");
        } 
        if (secondPromptIsPrinted){
            giveHint(guess, luckyNumber);
        }
        firstPromptIsPrinted = false; //Now
        secondPromptIsPrinted = true;

    } while (guess != luckyNumber);
```

Comment: Btw, there's no reason to have two if-statements there. Just put both statements in the first one...

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on but I'm pretty sure that creating more than one scanner on a single stream will lead you to problems. So don't initialise it in the loop or in a method that will be called multiple times.

Comment: Also there's no need for three lines to create and return `guess`. You could have written `int guess = scan.nexInt(); return guess;` or better just `return scan.nextInt()`.

Comment: Also assuming that the user is pressing the Enter key after each entry, this  character will not been consumed

Comment: @AlexHall I didn't include this in my code, but firstPromptIsPrinted = true before the loop, and secondPromptIsPrinted = false before the loop. Idk if that's useful... It just doesnt make sense that after "Enter a number between 1 and 20" it's like input() is called twice, but it only does that the 1st loop. Sorry if I sound dumb, I just don't like when things that should be so simple don't work.

Comment: There's some code you've omitted, I'm fairly sure, because as is this would not compile. Could you edit in a more complete implementation? Then we might be able to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I re-organized it a little to get rid of the static input method...This works : I think one change is the if condition around System.out.println( "Nope...");...

```
public class GuessGame {

    Scanner scan = null;

    public GuessGame() {
        scan = new Scanner ( System.in );
    }

    public int input() {
        int ltheResult;
        ltheResult = scan.nextInt ();
        return ltheResult;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GuessGame ltheClass = new GuessGame ();
        ltheClass.run ();
    }

    public void run () {
        int guess = 0;
        boolean firstPromptIsPrinted = true;
        boolean secondPromptIsPrinted = false;
        int luckyNumber = 10;

        do {
            if ( firstPromptIsPrinted ) {
                System.out.println ( "Enter a number between 1 and 20." );
            }
            guess = this.input ();

            if ( guess != luckyNumber ) {
                System.out.println ( "Nope ;). " );
            }
            // if (secondPromptIsPrinted){
            // giveHint(guess, luckyNumber);
            // }
            firstPromptIsPrinted = false; // Now
            secondPromptIsPrinted = true;

        }
        while ( guess != luckyNumber );
        System.out.println ( "Yes luckyNumber is [" + luckyNumber + "]" );
    }
}
```